# Angular data object key rename

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that I'm missing something simple.

I have an object in my `$scope` value. Now I want to reneame one of its property.

So assume I have

```
$scope.data = { prop1: value1, prop2: value2}
```

Now I want that my object will be:

`$scope.data = { newProp: value1, prop2: value2}`

I tried do

```
$scope.data.prop1 = newProp;
delete $scope.data.prop1;
```

but have not any success

How to do it correctly with angular data object?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

For some more info:

I tried to update this object from child controller, called `$scope.$parent.data`

Comment: How you do in Javascript same in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant

```
$scope.data.newProp = $scope.data.prop1;
delete $scope.data.prop1;
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/87j7g2vz/)

Comment: IF I do it ih this way, I have TypeError: Cannot set property 'newProp' of undefined

Comment: @Andrew then you're omitting something important. In your question, `$scope.data` is most certainly defined and is an object

Comment: yes, is already defined, exists and it is object. I iterate with this object in ng-repeat

Comment: @Andrew well obviously if the `data` object is in `$scope.$parent`, you'll need to change the references to `$scope.$parent.data`

Comment: Is it possible that new key appears at the same place as the previous one?

Comment: @Andrew the ordering of object keys is not important. If you're iterating the object with `ng-repeat`, I suggest you read this ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

Comment: why I asked you, because after I changed key it seems at the same place in object, but on page it appears at bottom (as the lastest element) and previous key is spliced on a page. But I want to show new key on the same place instead of previous one on page

Comment: @Andrew did you read the section of the Angular docs I linked to?

Comment: are you talking about converting object to array?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it now

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restructure complete object.

Try below code,

```
$scope.data = { prop1: value1, prop2: value2}

$scope.data1 = {
    newProp : $scope.data.prop1,
    prop2: $scope.data.prop2
} 
$scope.data = $scope.data1;
console.log($scope.data);
```

Comment: I think its not a good approach in my case because I have more than 500 properties in object and restructure it after every single property rename would not be a  good solution for me